# Is there a way to show different objects in two 3D view scene?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, customization

I want to show all the objects in the left 3d view window(1 ball, 1 cone, 2 cubes), and only show part of all objects in the right 3d view window (2 cubes).

Is there a way to implement this or is there a way to implement a customized UI window (python, Qt, etc.) to only show things I want to show?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can select the cubes like you already did and in the viewport where you want to see only them hit Numpad / to switch to _Local_ view. This limits the view to the selected objects. To go back from _Local_ view just press Numpad / again.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you! this is what I'm looking for. I have another question: Is it possible to make these 2 3D view scene asynchronous? For example, I want the red one on the left scene to be "hide_select" (wouldn't show any selected status), but the right one just as usual. Is it possible?